# Emulator error while starting an avd

Tags: android-emulator

I have installed adt bundle for windows(comes up with android 4.3) and have installed jdk7.
But after creating an avd when I start it the below error is displayed.
If anybody can tell where might be the issue and how to fix that I will be thankful

Starting emulator for AVD 'avd5'
Failed to create pbuf surface for FB 0x3004
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
extension WGL_ARB_make_current_read was not found

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this might be an issue of the emulator still being 32-bit as it can't allocate enough continuous amount of ram to the emulator.

The following [post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33930#c27) suggest various options you can explore:

- Disable OpenGLES emulation support by renaming \tools\lib\libOpenglRender.dll to libOpenglRender.dll.disabled.
- Reduce the amount of memory used by the emulator. Try 900MB, if that doesn't work, try 800MB, if that doesn't work, try 700MB, you get the idea. (I suggest start with a rather low value of 512 MB)
- Typing in the resolution manually rather than picking WXVGA720 or 800

I hope this helps...

Comment: Your solution at least starts the emulator but doesn't show anything. Blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Click `Edit your virtual device` and then unchecke `Use Host GPU` - I think it will work.